# Changing Text Dynamically Across Instances of a Tikzipicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm going to be using the same basic ellipse/boxes image throughout a project. I want to keep the way the image looks standard across the project, but I want to change the text each time I use the image. In this example, the ellipse contains the word "Depression" and the boxes contain "Sleep" and "Weight." But in another example, I may use a words like "Success," "GPA," "GRE."

Is there a way to do this (perhaps using some sort of dynamic variable structure)?

```
\newcommand{\myModelOneTwo}[1][]{%
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node(IV)[ellipse, draw, fill=blue!20, minimum width=75pt, minimum height=50pt] at (0,0) {Depression};
        \node(IVIndicator1)[rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, minimum width=50pt, minimum height=25pt] at (-1,-2) {Sleep};
        \node(IVIndicator2)[rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, minimum width=50pt, minimum height=25pt] at (1,-2) {Weight};
        \path [->,draw,thick] (IVIndicator1) -- (IV);
        \path [->,draw,thick] (IVIndicator2) -- (IV);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a command with 3 parameters.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric} 

\newcommand{\myModelOneTwo}[3]{% <<<<<<<<<<<
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node(IV)[ellipse, draw, fill=blue!20, minimum width=75pt, minimum height=50pt] at (0,0) {#1};
            \node(IVIndicator1)[rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, minimum width=50pt, minimum height=25pt] at (-1,-2) {#2};
            \node(IVIndicator2)[rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, minimum width=50pt, minimum height=25pt] at (1,-2) {#3};
            \path [->,draw,thick] (IVIndicator1) -- (IV);
            \path [->,draw,thick] (IVIndicator2) -- (IV);
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}}

\begin{document}
    
    \myModelOneTwo{Depression}{Sleep}{Weight}
    \bigskip
    
    \myModelOneTwo{Success}{GPA}{GRE}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

`\newcommand` defines a new macro which can accept multiple parameters (up to 9) including one optional.

To simplify your code, `tikz` also has an option to define styles, which we can be reused in the code. This is done either via `tikzset{}` or directly when we create pictures. I chose the first approach in the example. I also added the `global` style just to demonstrate you can even use already defines styles inside others.

The example

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\tikzset{
        general/.style = {
            draw,
            fill = blue!20,
        },
        myshapea/.style = {
            general,
            ellipse,
            minimum width=75pt,
            minimum height=50pt
        },
        myshapeb/.style = {
            general,
            rectangle,
            minimum width=50pt,
            minimum height=25pt
        },
        thickarrow/.style = {
            ->,
            draw,
            thick,
        },
}
\newcommand{\myModelOneTwo}[3][Depression]{
    \begingroup
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node [myshapea] (IV)           at ( 0, 0) {#1};
            \node [myshapeb] (IVIndicator1) at (-1,-2) {#2};
            \node [myshapeb] (IVIndicator2) at ( 1,-2) {#3};
            \path [thickarrow] (IVIndicator1) -- (IV);
            \path [thickarrow] (IVIndicator2) -- (IV);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \par
    \endgroup}


\begin{document}

\myModelOneTwo{Sleep}{Weight}

\bigskip

\myModelOneTwo[Success]{GPA}{GRE}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!!!